# Получить doctype iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не могу прочитать `<!DOCTYPE>` у `iframe`, его надо получить в виде строки. Для обычной страницы все просто: `document.doctype`. Предполагал, что для фрейма будет что то вроде `$("iframe").contents().find('doctype')`, но получаю пустую строку.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам читать doctype?)

Answer (score 0):

Получил таким образом:

```
document.getElementById('frame_id').contentWindow.document.doctype
```